# Extraer de varios Elementos un Elemento en concreto

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, xpath

estoy intentando sacar en XPath el dato de las descargas de Google Play. Pero cuando realizo la consulta, me arroja un listado de los datos que deseo obtener. Pero no se como extraer unicamente 1 dato y no los 5 o 6 que arroja. Por ejemplo, esto es lo que estoy haciendo, todo lo realizo con Google SpreadSheets.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.lfp.gi.main"; 
"//*/div[2]/span[contains(@class, 'htlgb')]")
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve:

```
August 23, 2018
30M
10,000,000+
6.5.2001
4.0.3 and up
Flag as inappropriate
Liga de Fútbol Profesional
```

Lo que quiero, es solamente extraer el **numero de Descargas** que ha tenido. ¿Que paso me falta?

Comment: Fumatamax: ¿Viste mi respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falta es agregar el número de instancia, además podrías usar un xPath más corto, por ejemplo

`=IMPORTXML("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.lfp.gi.main","(//span[contains(@class, 'htlgb')])[3]")`